How to sign Ethereum message in C#
I`m trying to convert this code to c#
const message = response.data.message;
    
const jsonProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL)
const ethersSigner = new ethers.Wallet(privatekey, jsonProvider);

const signature = await ethersSigner.signMessage(message);

but so far with out any luck. I found that I could sign message using Nethereum EthereumMessageSigner but can`t find a way for it to use the right RPC address. For example:
var account = new Account(PRIVATE_KEY);
var web3 = new Web3(account, RPC_URL);

var signer = new EthereumMessageSigner();
var signature = signer.EncodeUTF8AndSign(message, new EthECKey(PRIVATE_KEY));

Is it even possible in C#? (I'm trying to sign message in Blast mainnet)

You don't need a RPC in order to sign, just a private key and a message (it's just cryptography). Keep in mind that signing is chain agnostic, once you sign a message with a private key it's valid on all the chains, in fact it's valid everywhere (even offchain). I recommend this article to learn what a signature is and how it really works under the hood.
You can use the following snippet to sign the message "message" with the hardcoded privatekey:
using System;
using Nethereum.Signer;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var signer = new EthereumMessageSigner();
        var signature = signer.EncodeUTF8AndSign("message", new EthECKey("0xb5b1870957d373ef0eeffecc6e4812c0fd08f554b37b233526acc331bf1544f7"));
        Console.WriteLine(signature);
    }
}

